# How come the audio file embedded on the page still doesn't work after some JS coding?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio file `012.wav`, which is located in the same folder as my html and JS file. I'd like to embed it into html and JS with the code below. I can't press any buttons on the audio player on the page, except the playing speed only. What else is missing in my code, such that there is a player in the page, but I can't play it or turn the volume up or down?

Thanks a lot!

```js
const aud = document.querySelector('audio');
window.onload = load();

function load() {
  aud.load();
}
```

```html
<audio src="012.wav" controls type="audio/wav" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Comment: Are you sure your wav file is being loaded? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 I checked the console and there's nothing happened throughout. What other codes should I write to load the wav file, or to make sure that the page loads the wav file?

Comment: @Yogi It seems to be that my browser cannot access my audio file, and yours works with my code, in my browser. Thanks!